# MySQL encodes characters wrong on PC/Windows 10

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

When importing a dataset to Mysql (using the mysql-command) on Windows from command line (pied in with <) the contens of the database gets encoded wrong for norwegian characters æøåÆØÅ.

The file(s) are saved with Unix line ending and charset UTF-8 using Textpad.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS debate_system_100;

CREATE DATABASE debate_system_100;

ALTER DATABASE debate_system_100 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO events (event_name, company) VALUES
("System event", 1),
("Company 1 Landsmøte 2014", 2),
("Company 1 Landsmøte 2015", 2),
("Company 1 Landsmøte 2016", 2),
("Company 1 Landsmøte 2017", 2),
("Company 1 Landsmøte 2018", 2),
("Company 1 Landsmøte 2019", 2),
("Company 2 Landsmøte 2014", 3),
("Company 2 Landsmøte 2015", 3),
("Company 2 Landsmøte 2016", 3),
("Company 2 Landsmøte 2017", 3),
("Company 2 Landsmøte 2018", 3),
("Company 2 Landsmøte 2019", 3),
("Company 10 Landsmøte 2014", 11),
("Company 10 Landsmøte 2015", 11),
("Company 10 Landsmøte 2016", 11),
("Company 10 Landsmøte 2017", 11),
("Company 10 Landsmøte 2018", 11),
("Company 10 Landsmøte 2019", 11);
```

Comment: You need to use the new UTF8MBF https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: I assume the table was created after you changed the default character set/collation for the database?  What is the character set used by the shell from which you start mysql? What are the settings for character_set_client and character_set_connection in your session?  You can check that by adding "select @@character_set_client, @@character_set_connection;" to your script.

Comment: Yes, after the alter database. The charsets report latin1/latin1.

Comment: @Nesrene I guess this means that the database server thinks what is coming on the connection is latin1 when it is actually utf8.  If so, I think it will interpret ø which is encoded as c3b8 in utf8 as two latin1 characters, Ã¸

Comment: I do not know if it was the utf-8/latin1 conversion that was the problem, but when I moved it to a Linux-server the problem disappeared. I did some more research, and it seems Windows command prompt interprets via some strange codepages.

Answer (score 0):

See comment to oysteing. I probably was due to Windows codepages.